# Is there a way to hide type definitions?

Tags: rust

Coming from OCaml, it is quite easy to create a type which exists on some public interface, but whose definition is hidden. I'm trying to do the same in Rust and failing.

What I'm going for would look something like:

```
mod inner{
  pub(super) type MyActualType = ...
}
pub type MyType = inner::MyActualType

trait MyTypeExt{
...
}
impl MyTypeExt for MyType{
...
}
```

With the goal that the outside could only see the methods defined in `MyTypeExt`, not everything that `inner::MyType` has. For instance, `MyType` might be an `i32` that I only want to be able to create and use in very controlled contexts - I would like `a : MyType + b : MyType` to be a compiler error. (In the above code it is not.)

I realize I could do

```
pub struct MyType{v : MyActualType} //note the lack of visibility qualifier on v
```

But my understanding is that, in addition to crowding the syntax of the implementation with a bunch of wrapping and unwrapping, this may have performance implications. My understanding of the OCaml version is that, once visibility/type checking is done, the type would be treated as any other `i32` with no performance consequences.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like [opaque types](https://rust-lang.github.io/chalk/book/clauses/opaque_types.html)?

Comment: @tadman I was looking at that but not quite grokking it, and couldn't tell if it was specific to Chalk or what. I'm also not clear on exactly how to implement it, and the phrase "Although the above is not valid Rust syntax" doesn't spark confidence (nor the fact that the documentation there is unfinished)

Comment: I think Chalk just provides a tidy way of implementing it, as this is a relatively uncommon thing to do in Rust. You'll see the same approach used on "opaque type" `Future` results, so maybe that's another place to look for inspiration.

Comment: _"the type would be treated as any other i32 with no performance consequences."_ -- that's the same in Rust. In general, a struct with one field has the same memory representation as the field on its own.

Comment: @PeterHall While this is true in most cases, it is not guaranteed and relying on it it thus UB. If you explicitly want a struct to have the same representation as it's only field, you need to use #[[repr(transparent)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html)].

Comment: @PeterHall That's interesting, though I think there are still some actual differences (for instance, in theory mutation to the boxing struct and mutation to the underlying value are different, right? My implementation might never allow a practical difference, but I imagine the compiler will still need some level of distinction, right?

Comment: Using a newtyped struct is the proper way.

Comment: @leo848. UB is impossible without unsafe code. For the other part, I said "in general" to avoid having to have the rest of this discussion :)

Comment: @EdwardPeters I think you are using "boxing" incorrectly, which is causing people to go down unnecessary rabbit-holes. Boxing refers to a value that is stored on the heap and then accessed by reference. In Rust a field of a struct is only boxed if you explicitly make it boxed.

Comment: @PeterHall That sounds likely - I know that boxing is a concern for a similar process in Scala, but I guess there's no reason Rust would mirror that.

Comment: @PeterHall I explicitly said "relying on it", which you cannot do in safe code. Relying on a specific memory layout requires unsafe, e.g. via transmute or raw pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the for now unstable feature [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063).
With it you can define the inner module like this:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]
mod other {
    mod inner {
        pub(super) type MyActualType = i32;
    }
    pub type MyType = impl MyTypeExt;

    pub trait MyTypeExt: std::fmt::Display {
        fn print(&self) {
            println!("{self}")
        }
    }
    impl MyTypeExt for inner::MyActualType {}

    pub fn a() -> MyType {
        5i32 as inner::MyActualType
    }
}

use other::MyTypeExt;
fn main() {
    let a = other::a();

    // the following errors with:
    // error[E0369]: cannot add `{integer}` to `MyType`
    //let b = a + 9;

    // this is fine
    a.print();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=76eb24c944b51054d9c0569beaf6db3d)

Not exactly sure what you mean by this,

> this will actually have a boxed value at compile time.

But if you think it adds a runtime overhead to the struct you're wrong, single element structs or structs with only one non ZST struct are [laid out like their only non ZST field](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/structs-and-tuples.html), in this case like `MyActualType`

Comment: Thanks! QQ - does "for now unstable feature" mean "thing that is making its way into basic Rust syntax" or "thing that may become a stable feature in the future, but isn't likely to be part of the core language?" (I only just started hearing about features recently.)

Comment: I've added a link to the tracking issue, and there you can see it entered the final commit period. I'd expect this to stabilize within a few Rust releases because of that. In general unstable features might make it to stable some time in the future, stay unstable forever or be removed entirely so it really depends.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but is there a difference between "stable feature" and "part out out-of-the-box rust"? (i.e., if it becomes stable, would it still require the feature flag in order to be used?)

Comment: No, `feature`s are only allowed in nightly so if a feature stabilizes it's available out of the box.